# Python html module: return all occurrences of a tag inside subnode

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm going through [this page](http://www.senat.fr/dossier-legislatif/plfss2020.html) using `requests` and `lxml` modules.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page_dossier_legislatif = requests.get("http://www.senat.fr/dossier-legislatif/plfss2020.html")
tree = html.fromstring(page_dossier_legislatif.content)
```

I'm catching the `divs` where `id` = `timeline-6` and `timeline-8`, like this:

```
div_dynamic_content = tree.xpath('//*[@id="box-timeline"]/div[2]')[0]
list_div_steps = [div_dynamic_content.xpath("div[@id='timeline-6']"), div_dynamic_content.xpath("div[@id='timeline-8']")]
```

I'd like to get the links inside each of these nodes, but I'm not familiar with xpath, so I can't find the right xpath query, all I could find is the query below, which gives me a list of all the links in the page, not just the ones inside these `div`.

```
for div_etape_procedure in list_div_steps:
    print(div_etape_procedure.xpath('//a/@href'))
    print"--"

# Desired result should print :
# ['/amendements/2019-2020/98/accueil.html', '/interventions/crisom_plfss2020_1.html',
# '/interventions/criresume_plfss2020_1.html', '/scrupub/dossiers/plfss2020_scr.html#lec1']
# --
# ['/amendements/2019-2020/98/accueil.html', '/interventions/crisom_plfss2020_1.html',
# '/interventions/criresume_plfss2020_1.html', '/scrupub/dossiers/plfss2020_scr.html#lec1',
# '/leg/tas19-026.html']
```

Thanks.

PS: I'm not quite sure how to phrase the question, please feel free to change the title if you think of a better phrasing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to get *all links from divs with `@id='timeline-6'` and `@id='timeline-8'`*:

```
links = tree.xpath('//div[@id="timeline-6" or @id="timeline-8"]/ul//a/@href')
```

If you want to separate output for both divs:

```
links_6 = tree.xpath('//div[@id="timeline-6"]/ul//a/@href')
links_8 = tree.xpath('//div[@id="timeline-8"]/ul//a/@href')
```